# XSL-FO and XSLT integration. Why is the document ignoring the XSL-FO formatting?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am new to XSL-FO even new to XSLT and I am trying to integrate XSL-FO with XSLT so I can format a report using XSLT with page headers and footers also with pagination.

Everything I have tried so far generates the data, but does nothing for the formatting. What am I doing wrong? See the code below for a very simple hello world program. The text is supposed to be centered, but it is not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:template match='/rows'>
        <fo:root>

          <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="hello"
                        page-height="11in"  page-width="8.5in" margin-top="1in" 
                        margin-bottom="1in" margin-left="1in" margin-right="1in">
              <fo:region-body margin-top="1in" margin-bottom=".5in"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
          </fo:layout-master-set>

          <fo:page-sequence master-reference="hello">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
              <fo:block font-size="18pt" text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                Hello World!
              </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
          </fo:page-sequence>

        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is a sample of my XML:

```
<rows appMode="DEV" dateGenerated="">
    <row OfficeID="32" OfficeOutputOrder="1" Office="FO" OfficeTitle="First Office" RoomFaxID="88" RoomFaxNumber="" RoomNumberID="123">
        <personnel>
            <person PersonnelID="3870" Name="The Boss" PositionRoomNumberID="31" phone="555-647-5770" PAETitle="" PositionEmployeeTypeID="C" PositionOutputOrder="1" />
        </personnel>
        <officeFaxes>
             <fax RoomNumberID="123" RoomFaxNumber="" OfficeID="32" />
        </officeFaxes>
    </row>
</rows>
```

My desired output is for the text "Hello World" to print in the center of the page, like the XSL-FO code is (supposedly) telling it to do.

But currently, it appears in the upper left hand corner, both on my screen and printout.

How can I change that?

Comment: I tried your code samples at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiKb and the PDF generated there with the .NET version of Apache FOP has the `Hello World!` centered. So how do you run the XSLT and how to you convert the XSLT XSL-FO result to PDF?

Comment: _"But currently, it appears in the upper left hand corner, both on my screen and printout."_ - How are you viewing/printing the XSL-FO? Are you creating a PDF from the XSL-FO?

Comment: I can't see the jsfiddle from work because of our firewall. I'll check it out when I get home. I am using a SQL action from inside an EXTJS application to run it. the sql generates the xml which runs against the xslt. In it's simplest form, I put the xslt and xml in the same folder then put a stylesheet tag in the xml like so <?xml-stylesheet type = "text/xsl" href = "personnel_roster2.xslt"?> and still have the same issue.

Comment: Yes, this will go to a pdf. I just tried exporting a pdf and it also appears in the upper left hand corner. I would just like to see the simplest form work which is with the stylesheet tag in the xml file like above.

Comment: Are you viewing the XSL-FO on screen in a web browser or in an application that understands XSL-FO?